# Storing NSDate with system time zone in Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsdate

When I store a date in CoreData as [NSDate date], it is saved -5:30 difference. In core data I used attribute type as date.

How to store NSdate with timeZone?

**Update**: Here is the code I am using:

To store the date:

```
database = (DataBase*) [fetchResults objectAtIndex:indexVal]; 
[database setDate:[NSDate date]]; 
NSError error = nil; 
[managedObjectContext save:&error]
```

To retrieve the date:

```
DataBase *newDataBase = (DataBase) [fetchResults objectAtIndex:i]; 
NSDate *RetrivedDate = [newDataBase Date]; 
NSLog(@"Retrived Date :",RetrivedDate");
```

Before storing I log it. It shows current date and time. After storing I immediately fetched the date . but it showed 1 day delayed date..

Answer (score 1):

NSDate doesn't have a time zone. It stores dates as a number of seconds since a reference date in GMT.

The time zone is applied when you format the date for display using NSDateFormatter. This will pick up the device time zone by default.

Comment: But I stored date as [NSDate date] and retrived date as NSDate *dat = [db Date]; It shows one day and one hour difference..  How to resolve it.

Comment: And Also I checked the difference between the two dates immediately after stored in Db. then got a difference of one day. Please help

Comment: Can you update you question with code if you have a specific example?

Comment: Here Is My code
//storing
 database = (DataBase*) [fetchResults objectAtIndex:indexVal];
 [database setDate:[NSDate date]];
  
            NSError *error = nil;
            [managedObjectContext save:&error]

//retriving DataBase *newDataBase = (DataBase*) [fetchResults objectAtIndex:i];
                 NSDate *RetrivedDate = [newDataBase Date];
                 NSLog(@"Retrived Date :",RetrivedDate");
Here Retrived date gives 1 day and 1 hour and 15 min difference.

Comment: I did. while Storing before I log it. it shows current date and time . After stored I immediately fetched the date . but it showed 1 day delayed date.. AnyWay Thanks for your comments

Comment: I have just attempted this myself with a basic project. NSLogging the date before adding to and after retrieving a managed object gives exactly the same information in the log, which is the current time in GMT.

Comment: @jrturton there is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697771/save-date-in-gmt-timezone-using-core-data .Can you help me?

Comment: @SandeepAggarwal my answer is exactly the same. NSDate has no idea about time zones, it represents a specific moment in time. Yours is a problem with formatting output, not data storage.

Comment: @jrturton but when I saw it in database the date was in my phone's timezone, can't I see it in UTC?