# Save date in 'GMT' timezone in sqlite database

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I am using `Core-Data`to store date-time object.

Eg.  `2015-07-28T07:16:52+0000`  this is date in ISO format in `GMT` timezone.

But when I save this date in database

```
 NSString* dateString=@"2015-07-28T07:16:52+0000";
 NSDateFormatter* dateTimeformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateTimeformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
[dateTimeformatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

the resulting date which I see in database is `2015-07-28 12:46:52`

which is in `IST` according to my device's timezone

I tried to set timezone as well in dateFormatter but again the same response

```
 NSString* dateString=@"2015-07-28T07:16:52+0000";
 NSDateFormatter* dateTimeformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateTimeformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
[dateTimeformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[dateTimeformatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Even when I save the `[NSDate date]` directly in database , it saves the converted date according to device's timezone.

Why Core-data is not taking the timezone of NSDateFormatter into account?
Can anyone tell me how can I save the date in `GMT` in database irrespective of my device's timezone?

Comment: Try [dateTimeformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]]; or for system [dateTimeformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

Comment: Nop not working with [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"] and with systemTimezone it will take the local timezone

Comment: Not sure but try "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z" instead of "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

Comment: Maybe this helps [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"]; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254575/how-do-i-get-iso-8601-date-in-ios

Comment: OK so you understand that when you use `NSLog()` to display an `NSDate` object then it's displayed in the GMT timezone, right?

Comment: Cool. So explain how you are viewing this date.

Comment: by opening the sqlite database in third party s/w https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/liya/id455484422?mt=12

Comment: Are you storing the date as a String, or as a Date?

Comment: I am storing date as Date object

Comment: Get time interval from `TimeIntervalSince1970` and save it into DB.

Comment: @nanjunda isn't it is equivalent to saving the NSDate object?

Comment: No, TimeIntervalSince1970 is independent of Time zone. From documentation --  "The interval between the receiver and the reference date, 1 January 1970, GMT."

Comment: @nanjunda ok, I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve problem I was facing by doing some research and using [zpasternack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31719172/3632958) .I mentioned some findings for anyone who may face such problems related to timezone.

Findings:

1. The date which is saved in `database` (originally in any timezone) will be saved in `'GMT/UTC'` timezone.
2. The date which is seen in `local timezone` in database directly is because of `third party tool` which is used to see the data in database.
3. When date is taken out of `database` , then also it is in `'GMT/UTC'` timezone.
4. To see the date in `specific timezone` , the `NSDateFormatter` is used with the specific timezone specified.
5. The most important is `NSDate` object is always irrespective of any `timezone` and is always in `'GMT/UTC'`

Answer (score 2):

I think the behavior you're seeing is the 3rd party software converting it to your timezone for display. Timezones don't really matter except for display purposes (or if you need to convert between them for calculations, maybe). And, `NSDate`s on their own don't really correspond to any particular timezone, though internally they're represented as though they were GMT. [The doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html) says:

> The sole primitive method of NSDate, timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate,
>   provides the basis for all the other methods in the NSDate interface.
>   This method returns a time value relative to an absolute reference
>   date—the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT.

If you look at how the value is actually stored (which you can do with the sqlite3 command-line tool), you can see Core Data is storing it as the number of seconds since 1/1/01; there's no timezone involved. I have [an app](http://fat-apps.com/tasklog-mac/) which does a ton of date manipulation and stores dates in a Core Data store. It looks something like:

```
zach$ sqlite3 TaskLog.sqlite
sqlite> select ZSTARTTIME from ZTASK;
459924925.598104
459925327.3355
459925356.467429
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to know that if I save date '2015-07-28T07:16:52+0000' then since, it is in 'GMT' , will remain saved as 'GMT' and '2015-07-28T07:16:52+0530' is in 'IST' will also first converted back to 'GMT' and save as 'GMT' ?

Comment: Yes, that's basically correct. Regardless of which timezone you see when you output an `NSDate`, internally it's all GMT.